# What does it mean when Apple "hosts" my IAPs?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

In iTunesConnect, I see an option to make Apple host my in-app purchases for me. I was quite confused by this so I did some research and found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH3-SW4):

> Apple can host your non-consumable products for you. Apple provides a reliable and familiar experience for users and handles distributing products to their devices and restoring products if needed.

I am now even more confused.

About my IAP:

- Non-consumable
- Unlocks some extra content
- I set a value in `UserDefaults` indicating whether the IAP is purchased
- I check the value before displaying the extra content. If it is `false`, I set the views' `hidden` property to true.

As you can see, I don't need a "host" for anything. There is no need for Apple to "handle distributing products to their devices and restoring products if needed". I don't think any IAP needs to be "hosted".

I think I don't need Apple to host my IAP for me. Is this correct? Also, what is an example of an IAP that needs to be hosted by Apple? Why does it need hosting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based from what you are saying, your "extra content" is already baked into your bundle. So you are using the purchase mechanism as "the trigger" for your code to update the UserDefaults which in turn will allow the code to present the extra content.

Given this scenario, as you already stated, you have no need for hosted content. Apple hosted content is a means for you to be able to download the content to be consumed by the app. From a logistics standpoint, hosting through Apple makes it easier to manage and retrieve the right content. Otherwise, if you went the route of downloading content to your app, you would need to build/already have that infrastructure yourself.

Why download content? Your current mechanism is pretty easy to bypass. All someone needs to do is update your UserDefaults, which can easily be done in jailbroken devices. Once done and since your content is baked into your bundle, they will then get that content.

Going to an example. Let's say you have a game where you are selling levels. In total you have 10 levels. The app itself is a free download and you supply the user with 1 unlocked level. Users will need to purchase the other levels. Let's also say levels are large. Like 50MB each. This means that if you baked in all your content, your app bundle will be larger than 150MB, which means that they will have to be on Wifi to download the app. And I already cited the issue around how your UserDefaults can be used to unlock the content for jailbroken devices. This scenario would be good for hosted content, whether it be through Apple or other means. Each level would then be individually downloaded upon purchase. Hosted content also provides other flexibility like decoupling content from the app bundle, which means if you are updating content, you are not forced to update the app.

From the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html).

> You can embed that content in your app’s bundle or you can download it
>   as needed—each approach has its advantages and disadvantages. If you
>   include too little content in your app bundle, the user must wait for
>   even small purchases to be downloaded. If you include too much in your
>   app bundle, the initial download of the app takes too long, and the
>   space is wasted for users who don’t purchase the corresponding
>   products. Additionally, if your app is too large, users won’t be able
>   to download it over cellular networks.
>
> Embed smaller files (up to a few megabytes) in your app, especially if
>   you expect most users to buy that product. Content in your app bundle
>   can be made available immediately when the user purchases it. However,
>   to add or update content in your app bundle, you have to submit an
>   updated version of your app.
>
> Download larger files when needed. Separating content from your app
>   bundle keeps your app’s initial download small. For example, a game
>   can include the first level in its app bundle and let users download
>   the rest of the levels when they’re purchased. Assuming your app
>   fetches its list of product identifiers from your server, and not
>   hard-coded in the app bundle, you don’t need to resubmit your app to
>   add or update content that is downloaded by your app.

Comment: Wonderful explaination.